# GPG keys copied, not working

Tags: gpg

I have copied my GPG keys from 1 server to another, on the first server everything is working correctly, on the new I get the following:
(I have included the output of list-keys and list-secret-keys

```
[www@localhost data]$ gpg escs_hr_feed.pgp

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Encrypt <encrypt@email.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 8E7BFE3A, created 2015-06-24 (main key ID B943D3E2)

gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 8E7BFE3A, created 2015-06-24
      "Encrypt <encrypt@email.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: General error
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
[www@localhost data]$ gpg --list-keys
/home/www/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
----------------------------
pub   2048R/B943D3E2 2015-06-24
uid                  Encrypt <encrypt@email.com>
uid                  Master <master@email.com>
sub   2048R/8E7BFE3A 2015-06-24
sub   2048R/6E704692 2015-06-24

[www@localhost data]$ gpg --list-secret-keys
/home/www/.gnupg/secring.gpg
----------------------------
sec   2048R/B943D3E2 2015-06-24
uid                  Master <master@email.com>
uid                  Encrypt <encrypt@email.com>
ssb   2048R/8E7BFE3A 2015-06-24
ssb   2048R/6E704692 2015-06-24
```

Comment: Have you imported the secret and PUBLIC key?

Comment: What happened between the “You need a passphrase …” prompt and “gpg: cancelled by user”? If nothing happened, that would be because gpg is trying to contact some keyring, failing, and failing to report the error.

Comment: What's the version of gpg (`gpg --version`)? What is the output of `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be that if you `sudo su -` to the user, you cannot use gpg, you need to log directly in as the user.

(At least on my companies server setup)